# How to get the value(number) from a clicked number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the clicked number

[image]

and load the data from the database according to this number. The column that the numbers are stored is named as id.

I have this code in order to display the numbers(id)...

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM work WHERE username='$username' order by id asc limit 10;";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                if ($result != 0) {


                    $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++) {
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        echo '<a href="' .kotoula(). '">' .$id. '</a>';
                    }

                }
```

And then I want to load the data from this number in a form which the code for the form is...

```
function kotoula() {
                    $username = $_SESSION["username"];


                    if($query = mysql_query("SELECT job_title,company,website,start_date,end_date,start_year,end_year,work_history FROM work WHERE id>'$id' AND username='$username' order by id asc limit 10") or die(mysql_error()))
                    {
                        if(mysql_num_rows($query)>=1){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                            $job_title = $row['job_title'];
                            $company = $row['company'];
                            $website = $row['website'];
                            $start_date = $row['start_date'];
                            $end_date = $row['end_date'];
                            $start_year = $row['start_year'];
                            $end_year = $row['end_year'];
                            $work_history = $row['work_history'];
                            }
                        }                                           
                    }
                }
```

Comment: When clicking in <a> send its text: _$("a").click(function(){ numbers( $(this).text() )});_

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes can you explain please your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in the URL using GET. Something like:

```
http://yoururl.com/user.php?id=12345
```

Then, user.php will receive that value on $_GET array. Example:

```
$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: the number are not always the same, it is dynamic, they change according to the number of data that the user has in the database

Comment: Then select that ID on the database with a SQL query and make an echo on the URL.

Something like: http://yoururl.com/user.php?id=<? echo $userID; ?>